# car and cdr in Scheme are driving me crazy

Tags: scheme

I'm facing a problem with the `car` and `cdr` functions

for example:

first I defined a list called it x

```
(define x (a (bc) d ( (ef) g ) ))
```

so x now is equal to `(a (bc) d ( (ef) g ) )`

now for example I need to get the **g** from this list using only `car` and `cdr`
(!! noshortcuts as caddr cddr !!) the correct answer is:

```
(car(cdr(car(cdr(cdr(cdr x))))))
```

But how? I work according to the rules (the `car` gives the head of the list and `cdr` gives the tail)

and instead of getting the answer above, I keep reaching wrong answers.
Can anyone help me in understanding this ... give me a step or a way to solve it step by step?

Comment: @ (all the great people that answerd my question)
I understand what u guys wrote , just have some questions
| do u guys mean the when I reach somthin like ( (g) ) I should use car to get rid of the outer parantheses to get (g) ?|

Comment: One of the things that always turns me off about LISP-based languages is the **INCREDIBLY** bad naming-scheme they all seem to share

Comment: When you've got `(g)`, you've got a list, and you need an atom.  Use `car` to get the first element.  Similarly, if you've got `((g))`, you need to use `car` twice, first to get to `(g)` and then to `g`.

Comment: @BlueRaja You probably know anyway, but `car` and `cdr` were named after two registers from the first machine to run a LISP interpreter. It's a holdover, but hey [so is lambda](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-12.html#footnote_Temp_99).

Comment: @new123456: huh?  Lambda is not a holdover - it's named after [lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), the very thing it represents (it's also been around for a lot longer than programming languages)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: but why is lambda calculus named after lambda? ;)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try to do it step by step:

- **cdr** yields the list without the first element
- **car** yields the first element of a list

  ```
                                x         is  (a (bc) d ( (ef) g ))
                           (cdr x)        is  (  (bc) d ( (ef) g ))
                      (cdr (cdr x))       is  (       d ( (ef) g ))
                 (cdr (cdr (cdr x)))      is  (         ( (ef) g ))
            (car (cdr (cdr (cdr x))))     is            ( (ef) g )
       (cdr (car (cdr (cdr (cdr x)))))    is            (      g )
  (car (cdr (car (cdr (cdr (cdr x))))))   is                   g
  ```

Comment: @Curd|| so in the 5th line I used car to remove the outer parentheses (or the list) ? if so, Why i didnt remove the second parentheses on line 5 again by using another car before reaching the inside and using cdr ( i mean why we postpond the car to line 7 ?

Comment: car at line 5 (i.e. `(car ( (ef) g ))` would leave you with `(ef)`.  If you're looking to get g, you mustn't throw it away.  ;)  car doesn't remove the parentheses, it returns the first item in the following list.  If the list only contains one item, then you get that item, no longer in a list.

Answer (score 5):

do the transforms one at a time.  cdr gives you a list without the first element, car gives you the first element.

```
(cdr (a (bc) d ( (ef) g ) )) -> ( (bc) d ( (ef) g ) )
(cdr ( (bc) d ( (ef) g ) ))  -> ( d ( (ef) g ) )
(cdr ( d ( (ef) g ) ))       -> ( ( (ef) g ) )
(car ( ( (ef) g ) ))         -> ( (ef) g )  <- pulls the first element out, which happens to be a list itself
(cdr ( (ef) g ))             -> (g)
(car (g))                    -> 'g
```

Answer (score 2):

this is easy/compact way to get the value of the list.

```
(cadr (cadddr x))
```

by combining repeating functions, you get elegant easy to read statement.

Comment: OP specifically asked without shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

```
(cdr x) = ((bc) d ( (ef) g ) )
(cdr(cdr x)) = (d ( (ef) g ) )
(cdr(cdr(cdr x))) = (( (ef) g ) )
(car(cdr(cdr(cdr x)))) = ( (ef) g )
(cdr(car(cdr(cdr(cdr x))))) = (g)
(car(cdr(car(cdr(cdr(cdr x)))))) = g
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a REPL (read-eval-print-loop) such as [csi](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/csi.1.html)? That way you can work on this interactively, which will make it easier for you to learn and work through this (and other) problems using Scheme.

Answer (score 0):

do it iteratively. Also, realize that scheme always looks backwards.

```
(cdr x) = ( (b c) ...)
(cdr (cdr (cdr x))) = (( (ef) g))
(car (cdr (cdr (cdr x)))) = ((ef) g)
(cdr (car (cdr (cdr (cdr x))))) = (g)
(car (cdr (car (cdr (cdr (cdr x)))))) = 'g
```

hope that helps